# canvas performance of stroke vs fill

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I'm rendering some pretty complex polygons on a map and I'm noticing that when using `context.stroke()` redrawing these polygons (zooming and panning) is lightning fast. However, when filling these polygons with `context.fill()` it feels almost 10x slower.

Is `fill` that expensive? Are there any ways to get `stroke`-like performance with a fill?

Comment: Just a wild guess but I think it makes sense as `stroke` simply has to following the preexisiting path and pad it with pixels, while `fill` has to find a whole lot of pixels _inside_ the path (and the path might even overlap itself!), so it would be slightly slower. I think these are the kind of limitations you will have to work with. Would be interested to know more, though.

Comment: @somethinghere Seems legit. What's also troubling is if you want to render this on a high resolution display (retina) you are essentially making it twice as worse. Too bad there isn't better high-dpi support other than essentially doubling the size of the canvas. I'm mostly surprised that canvas, being hardware accelerated in chrome, is still subject to such simple performance caveats.

Comment: I'm guessing the optimisation comes down to _not drawing everything_. I don't know how yours is setup but all tutorials I have seen draw everything on every call to `window.requestAnimationFrame`, which is very intense. There's the `restore()` and `save()` methods for saving certain predefined results and loading them back in, which could improve performance?

Comment: @stewart715. So do a [performance test](https://jsperf.com/) and let us know if your apps strokes &  fills vary. If the paths of your `.fill`'ed polys aren't changing you can draw them once to a buffer canvas and `drawImage(buffercanvas,...)` rather than having canvas recalculate them every time.

Comment: @somethinghere. Note that `save` and `restore` don't save canvas drawings. They just save and restore the context properties (styles, transformations, etc).

Comment: @markE wonderful - I did not know that, like I mentioned, I was just guessing about potentials. I am learning about canvas and haven't found a use for these methods myself yet.

Comment: @somethinghere I would add to @markE's comment that `save()` and `restore()` can be cumbersome, definitely not a good choice to improve perfs ;-)